# Modifying a 2D malloc array within a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

`getTable` takes the contents of a 2d array of structs and copies `int`s stored in
it to `table`. However when I try to read anything from `table` in `main` I get a `Segmentation fault` error at runtime.

```
void getTable(char*s1, char*s2, char**table)
{
/*
SKIP SOME STUFF
*/

    table = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(s2Len+1));
    for (i = 0 ; i <= s2Len; i++)
        table[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(s1Len+1));
    for (i = 0 ; i <= s2Len; i++)
        for (j = 0 ; j <= s1Len; j++)
            table[i][j] = '0' + tmpTable[i][j].num;

//prints what table points to correctly
    for (i = 0 ; i <= s2Len; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0 ; j <= s1Len; j++)
            printf("%2c", table[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{

    char ** table; // for number table

/*
SKIP SOME STUFF
*/

// gives error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    getTable(s1,s2,table);
    printf("getTable test\n");
    int i, j;
    //
    for (i = 0 ; i <= strlen(s2); i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0 ; j <= strlen(s1); j++)
            printf("%c ", table[i][j]);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Print the value of the pointer table before and after the getTable() call. Did it change?

Comment: Maybe try allocating memory for the table in main? So put  table = malloc(sizeof(char*)*(s2Len+1)); just before getTable in main.

Answer (score 1):

You modified a local variable (table) in the sub-function(getTable) but I don't see where you passed it back to the caller.   I think the caller(main) is still looking at its original value of table.

If you initialized main's value of table to NULL,   and printf with the %p the value of table after you call your function I think it will still point to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void getTable(char*s1, char*s2, char***pTable)
{
    char **table = *pTable;
     .... rest of code ...
}
```

and in main:

```
int main(void)
{
    char ** table; // for number table
    getTable(s1,s2, &table);
    ... rest of code ...
}
```

In the original code, you allocate memory for the table parameter, but the local table in main does not get this value, so you need to pass the address of this local to your function instead.
Another way is to make your getTable function return a ** that you can assign to the local table in main:

```
char **getTable(char*s1, char*s2)
{
    char **table;
     .... rest of code ...
    return table;
}

int main(void)
{
   char **table;

   table = getTable(s1,s2);
   ... rest of code ...
}
```